# SurfaceView UpdateWindow() - NullpointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I have a custom video player which uses SurfaceView inside a fragment.

```
/* Notify SDK on Surface Creation */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {

    if(null==m_strVideoPath)
        return;
    LogUtil.e(TAG, "initiating player now..");
    initPlayer(m_strVideoPath);
    playVideo(m_strVideoPath);

}
```

I see lot crashes in store with a nullpointer exception in SurfaceView updateWindow method. Here are the crash logs:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:603)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1909)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1038)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5651)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Looking into source code of SurfaceView class at 603 line gives me:
`if (redrawNeeded) {
602                        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "finishedDrawing");
603                        mSession.finishDrawing(mWindow);
604                    }`

I couldn't reproduce this crash on any of my test devices, wondering if someone could help in understanding this scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: same issue facing...